# {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"inactive organization"}

Tags: oauth2

I am making POST  request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token to get the access token. Which is resulting in a 400 response code with the message - 
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"inactive organization"}

What can be the meaning of this error?

Answer (score 1):

**Server Sends a Response**

After the request is verified, Salesforce sends a response to the client. Token responses for the OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer token flow follow
the same format as authorization_code flows, although no refresh_token is ever issued.

Note: A SAML OAuth 2.0 bearer assertion request looks at all the previous approvals for the user that include a refresh_token.
If matching approvals are found, the values of the approved scopes are combined and an access_token is issued (with "token_type" value "Bearer"). If no previous approvals included a refresh_token, no approved scopes are available,
and the request fails as unauthorized.

**Errors**

If there is an error in processing the SAML bearer assertion, the server replies with a standard OAuth error response, including an error
and an error description containing additional information regarding the reasons the token was considered invalid. Here is a sample
error response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
{
"error":"invalid_grant",
"error_description":"Audience validation failed"
}
```

[Refer  this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/extend_code.pdf) for Detail Answers and Search for **"Using SAML Bearer Assertions"** this heading in pdf

Comment: @Smita : If this answer has solved your issue - Or You got in above answer - what you were looking for then please accept above answer as solution. It will help others too.